# Programmatically changing Ebay pictures through Trading API

Tags: python, ebay-api

This question isn't specific to Python at all, given that I know all the same HTTP API calls are made regardless of what SDK is being used.

I have a bunch of listings (hundreds) that I need to change programmatically. The need is just to change the Variation pictures of an item. Using the ReviseItem API has not been working as expected for me.

Details:

If I do a GetItem request for itemID 332121070278, I get the following response back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-02-05T16:46:02.399Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1035</Version>
    <Build>E1035_INTL_API_18562923_R1</Build>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>332121070278</ItemID>
        <Variations>
            <Pictures>
                <VariationSpecificName>Colour</VariationSpecificName>
                <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                    <VariationSpecificValue>Navy</VariationSpecificValue>
                    <PictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/3e11c104-311f-4faa-b308-e6d40f6a3c6a.jpg</PictureURL>
                    <ExternalPictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/3e11c104-311f-4faa-b308-e6d40f6a3c6a.jpg</ExternalPictureURL>
                </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                    <VariationSpecificValue>Olive</VariationSpecificValue>
                    <PictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/881a11fe-bb73-4d3a-a556-cdecae2ee723.jpg</PictureURL>
                    <ExternalPictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/881a11fe-bb73-4d3a-a556-cdecae2ee723.jpg</ExternalPictureURL>
                </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                    <VariationSpecificValue>Nearly Black</VariationSpecificValue>
                    <PictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/211f43f9-a4fd-40fd-9712-743e5ab328d0.jpg</PictureURL>
                    <ExternalPictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/211f43f9-a4fd-40fd-9712-743e5ab328d0.jpg</ExternalPictureURL>
                </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                    <VariationSpecificValue>Wine</VariationSpecificValue>
                    <PictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/27f7768e-3987-4ff4-9440-614c0853b0cb.jpg</PictureURL>
                    <ExternalPictureURL>https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.linnlive.com/b3bb06dbe22847df07835760a144c5dd/27f7768e-3987-4ff4-9440-614c0853b0cb.jpg</ExternalPictureURL>
                </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
            </Pictures>
        </Variations>
    </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

So in order to submit my ReviseItem request in the Python SDK, I did the following:

```
def reviseItem(opts):
    try:

        api = Trading(debug=opts.debug, config_file=opts.yaml, appid=opts.appid,
                      certid=opts.certid, devid=opts.devid, warnings=True, timeout=20, siteid='3')

        response = api.execute('ReviseItem', {'Item': {
            'ItemID': '332121070278',
            'Variations': {
                'Pictures': {
                    'VariationSpecificPictureSet': [
                        {
                            'PictureURL': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519',
                            'ExternalPictureURL': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519',
                            'VariationSpecificValue': 'Wine'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }})
        #dump(api, full=False)
        return response


    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
        print(e.response.dict())
```

... Which, when I check the request that actually went out, produced the expected XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ReviseItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>...</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>332121070278</ItemID>
        <Variations>
            <Pictures>
                <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
                    <ExternalPictureURL>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519</ExternalPictureURL>
                    <PictureURL>https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519</PictureURL>
                    <VariationSpecificValue>Wine</VariationSpecificValue>
                </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
            </Pictures>
        </Variations>
    </Item>
</ReviseItemRequest>
```

Seems totally correct to me. And I can make other ReviseItem API calls that work (e.g. I can successfully change the title of a listing using ReviseItem), but changing the Variation images is giving me the error `"ReviseItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10007, Internal error to the application. Internal error to the application."` every time

Comment: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Basics/Call-ErrorHandling.html  --> Please note that error 10007 ("Internal error to the application") indicates an error on the server side, not an error in your application.

Comment: @Marichyasana thank you. I did get confused about that at first but soon realized it was actually a respnse from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the API doesn't accept VariationSpecificPictureSet without VariationSpecificName. My api call above works perfectly with a small amendment:

```
response = api.execute('ReviseItem', {'Item': {
            'ItemID': '332121070278',
            'Variations': {
                'Pictures': {
                    'VariationSpecificName': 'Colour',
                    'VariationSpecificPictureSet': [
                        {
                            'PictureURL': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519',
                            'ExternalPictureURL': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0740/6535/products/wine_1_43df4936-4a20-4419-8643-40575a9bb457.jpg?v=1479773519',
                            'VariationSpecificValue': 'Wine'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }})
```